# Is there a way to output something every 5 minutes during another process in PHP?

Tags: php, cron, timeout

I have a cronjob which imports a huge file and then processes it. The import process takes a lot of time however after 600 seconds the server I am running the script on aborts the cronjob (timeout). After talking to a server technician he told me I needed to **output** something during the process of importing in order for the script to not abort after 10 minutes.

My question now is: let's say we have a function `import()` which imports the file (this function takes approximately 20 minutes to run). Is there any way to simultaneously `echo` an output every for example 5 minutes? Or is this not possible due to the fact that PHP code is always processed in sequence?

Comment: That depends on hwo you import the file. Show some sample code

Comment: Could you not simply up the maximum time execution limit? (e.g ini_set('max_execution_time', 3000))

Answer (score 1):

If it is an iterative process you could set a variable `$last_echo` with the value of `time()`.
Then on each iteration check if `time() - $last_echo > 300`.

Example:

```
$last_echo = time();
while (true) {
  //Do process
  if (time() - $last_echo > 300) {
    echo '.';
  }
}
```

Comment: I thought cron would send emails of any output to the console, would it work if you just output to a log file?

Comment: You could output to a log, but that won't be emailed to you by default.
You can also try to raise the `max_execution_time` to let's say `3600`. Might be a fix.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but I tried all of the different fix approaches but it seems they don't change anything.
@RiggsFolly no apparently the output needs to be directly and not into a log file.

Comment: @L00_Cyph3r unfortunately this will not work if I have one single function without an iterative process.

Comment: Well show us the piece of code that does the import then we can actually see what we are dealing with, rather than just guessing